# HTML sitemap link to root

Tags: seo, sitemap

I have a HTML sitemap composed by the following elements (the sitemap is linked to my footer)

```
logo (linking to / )
link for the first  block of 150 links
link for the second block of 150 links
....
```

I have now a SEO MAGIC GURU, that cannot explain me why, but he stated, that the logo must link to the frontpage and every page with the 150 block of links should link to the /sitemap. He says simply "that is what google likes". I'm developer. I know how the crawlers work and, the well written crawlers (and we can assume that google crawlers are state of art crawlers), parse all links from a page and just visit/crawl links that it didn't visited before. So the link for the "/sitemap" on all pages, to the bots, won't bring nothing, right?

Do I missed something or the SEO-VOODOO-GURU is right?

p.s: i do have a sitemap.xml, but as analyzed by me before, the HTML sitemap is really appreciated by google.

Comment: "every page with the 150 block of links should link..." - what do you mean by this? Literally that every page with a large chunk of text should link to the sitemap, but that other lesser pages need not?

Comment: imagine a car portal where every link (from these 150 links) is a show view for one car, something like /cars/1, /cars/2, /cars/n.

Comment: Ah ok, I somehow misread "links" for "text". I'll update my answer...

Comment: Or is your "SEO GURU" suggesting that your sitemap should link to every single page, not simply to the _blocks of 150 links_?

Comment: @w3d YES, that is what he says that "google likes"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the logo must link to the frontpage

AFAIK there is no SEO benefit of doing this, as long as there is some other link elsewhere on the page that links to the homepage.

However, it is common convention to do so and consequently users often expect this. So it can improve useability, but I don't think this has any SEO benefit specifically.

> every page with the 150 block of links should link to the /sitemap

If I have understood correctly, I don't think this just applies to "page[s] with 150 block of links" (that is irrelevant IMO), but to *every* page. Including a link to the sitemap on every page *could* benefit SEO by simply improving the internal linking of the site and hence its ability to get spidered by the search engines. This can also improve usability in case the user gets lost - a sitemap link is often found in the page footer (common convention).

A smaller site that already has good internal links probably wouldn't benefit so much SEO-wise from including a link to the sitemap, but there could still be a usability benefit.

> sitemap should link to every single page, not simply to the blocks of 150 links [COMMENT]

I don't think this would necessarily provide any SEO benefit in your case. What the SEO "guru" might be trying to avoid is deeply nested links, where pages are nested 5 or 6 levels deep. There is potentially a limit to how deep the SE spider will go. But I don't think that applies in your case (homepage -> sitemap -> carportal -> car). And it is probably best to avoid 1000's of links on a single HTML (sitemap) page (this is not an XML sitemap). On an HTML sitemap it is perfectly acceptable to categorise the links, which is what you seem to be doing. An HTML sitemap is, after all, as much as (if not more so) a benefit to your users than SEO.

YouTube video by Matt Cutts:
[Is it still important to offer a site map to users?](http://youtu.be/t5LIlkhxl2s)

Comment: perfect. You are right. To usability yes, for SEO, in a page that just bots will access, you are right and i do think the same.